# Is it possible to add arbitrary folders to the media scanner?

Tags: storage, media-scanner

I have a Samsung Captivate Glide and it's got 4 gigs of storage that isn't main storage and isn't SD card memory. It shows up as a separate section under `settings->storage` and it's mounted on `/sdcard/usbStorage`

The **real** physical SD card is mounted under `/sdcard/external_sd`.

So it's 4 gigs of free space, but I can't use it for anything because the media scanner won't pick up anything I put in there.

Is there a way to force the scanner to search particular directories?

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable using the command line then you could use the directions in [Can I trigger a media scan via the command line?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51784/can-i-trigger-a-media-scan-via-the-the-command-line/)

Pass `file:///sdcard/usbStorage` to the media scanner.

```
#!/system/bin/sh

export ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app
export ANDROID_CACHE=/cache
export ANDROID_DATA=/data
export ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec
export ANDROID_ROOT=/system
export BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/filterfw.jar
export EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/sdcard
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib

am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///sdcard/usbStorage
```

I can't test this for you so let us know if it works.