# Can I trigger a media scan via the command line?

Tags: media-scanner

Is it possible to trigger the media scanner to update its DB via the command line?

I have an [SSH server installed on my Android device](http://kennystechtalk.blogspot.com/2013/06/dropbear-ssh-server-on-android.html?utm_source=Stack+Exchange&utm_medium=single&utm_content=CLI+MediaScanner&utm_campaign=Stack+Exchange) and I copy files to/from over the same link. It would be great if I could also trigger a re-scan for the media scanner.

I am aware that there are applications on the market to do this via the UI but this is not what I want.

Any help fully appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The SSH server doesn't set all the necessary environment variables so it is easier to use a shell script.

```
#!/system/bin/sh

export ANDROID_ASSETS=/system/app
export ANDROID_CACHE=/cache
export ANDROID_DATA=/data
export ASEC_MOUNTPOINT=/mnt/asec
export ANDROID_ROOT=/system
export BOOTCLASSPATH=/system/framework/core.jar:/system/framework/core-junit.jar:/system/framework/bouncycastle.jar:/system/framework/ext.jar:/system/framework/framework.jar:/system/framework/android.policy.jar:/system/framework/services.jar:/system/framework/apache-xml.jar:/system/framework/filterfw.jar
export EXTERNAL_STORAGE=/mnt/sdcard
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib

am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///mnt/sdcard
```

When successful:

```
# rescan-media
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED dat=file:///mnt/sdcard }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

This works on Cyanogenmod 9.1. Depending on your system the environment may be slightly different.

Note: In later versions of Cyanogenmod / Android the SD card may be mounted at `/storage/sdcard0`. Make sure you know where your card is mounted or this will never work. [Diskinfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.kuder.diskinfo) may help here.

Thanks to Dan Hulme for pushing me in the right direction.

References:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1752749
http://intwoplacesatonce.com/
http://kennystechtalk.blogspot.co.uk/2013/08/start-android-media-scanner-from.html

Comment: On Paranoid Android (CM10 / JB 4.1) this causes an immediate reboot. Not sure if there is a problem with the ROM or something has changed. Will investigate.

Comment: On CM11 this does not work.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Have you used the correct path? In CM10 this has changed from /mnt/sdcard to /storage/sdcard0.

Comment: Sorry I meant to explain more. Im running CM11 Android 4.4.2 Kit Kat. I have tried /sdcard/, /sdcard/Music. My sdcard is very empty. I am trying to refresh Google Play Music.

Comment: However, this does work on Google Glass (Android 4.0.4).

Comment: This refers to the Android Media Scanner. I don't know enough about Play Music to help: I've barely looked at it, but it's a cloud service so I can't imagine it works anything like the Media Scanner.

Comment: This apparently no longer works on Android 8.1. Even the developer tools GUI, which uses the same broadcast, no longer works.

Comment: I have not kept up with how Android works, as it do so really quite badly. No doubt many things have been broken since this was answered. A shame but there we go.