# gallery shows 0 images/videos available and file manager browser shows 0 B for images videos and music

Tags: music, images

My Android gallery is not showing images and videos (these things are present in my phone and memory card and viewed through file manager in gallery single image). Even the file manager browser shows 0 B for music videos and images, while documents and apk files are shown, also remaining free memory is shown correctly.

I don't know what to do as I restored my device once, but the problem is still present. Before performing the reset process I removed my sd card, after a while something like gallery and process not working appears.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your SD card is not damaged or corrupted, it seems that media scanner has not picked up your media!

---

You could try an app like [Force Media Scan](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.promethyl.force.media.scanner&hl=en) to force it to run. NOTE: I have not tested this app. There are many apps to do this [this one has a widget for it](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jim2&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5qaW0yIl0) (also not tested by me). Some applications like PowerAmp will automatically scan for media when first booted also.

---

Alternatively you could try to update or re-install Google Play Services (though this may cause issues with other applications). If you are a bit more techie you could try [running media scanner via commandline](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/51784/can-i-trigger-a-media-scan-via-the-the-command-line).

---

Finally I found [this article](http://www.droidviews.com/memory-card-media-files-not-detected-on-phone-here-is-the-fix/) where the author says none of the apps worked, but the following did (note it was on a Galaxy S3, but I don't know what device you have):

1. Turn  off you phone and pull out the memory card.
2. Insert the memory card in a memory card reader. If your desktop or laptop has an MMC slot, it will do.
3. Wait till you can see the Drive of the memory card (Drive E, F, G, H, I, J, for example).
4. Do not open the card in PC.
5. Now click on the “Start” (Windows) button on your PC and type “cmd”. Hit the Enter key and you will see a command box.
6. Now type the following command at the cursor blink: `chkdsk x: /r`
7. Here “x” is the value/name of the memory card Drive. In my case it was H, so I typed `chkdsk h: /r`
8. Now hit the Enter key on your keyboard and wait till Windows checks your card and fixes it.
9. When it is finished, safely remove your card and insert it into the phone.
   Reboot the phone and now you should be able to see your media files on your phone’s apps.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying all the suggested solutions but none of them worked.
After trying many apps for scanning the media, finally "Folder Media Scanner" app worked for me and now I am able to see the images and videos in the gallery(issue exists for music files though).
Note: I am using Sony Xperia C with Android 4.2.2 version.

Comment: Could you link the app?

Answer (score 0):

In case of Android 4.0.4 / 4.1 you should do the following steps:

1. Settings → Apps → All. Locate the following:

   - ProtectedMediaScanner → Clear data & Force stop
   - ProtectedMediaScannerTrigger → Clear data & Force stop
   - Media Storage → Clear data & Force stop
2. Restart your Android phone. Turn it off, then on again. Let it rest for 10-15 minutes. Afterwards your media files should be available by Gallery and Music player.

You should also check for the existance of a ".nomedia" (hidden) file in any directory. This file is placed there by system for some operations where media availability should be prohibited. Sometimes it is left there by unexpected interruption. Usually while connected to USB, or incomming call. Remove/delete/rename it, and you should be on track again.

Cheers