# Why Whatsapp images and videos are not showing in my gallery?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, motorola-moto-g

I have bought Moto G 2<sup>nd</sup> generation. I have Whatsapp installed in my mobile and it working very well. As you all know all Whatsapp images and videos will get displayed in gallery.

I decided to hide these images and videos. I have searched over net and found some useful links. Based on that, I have placed a `.nomedia` folder under `whatsapp/media` folder. After this, when I checked gallery, all images and videos from Whatsapp are gone. Eureka... Then I reverted the changes that I have made. That is I deleted the `.nomedia` file from `media` directory. But unfortunately, I couldn't find my Whatsapp images and videos in gallery.

So I cleared cache of Whatsapp via settings. Then I restarted my device. Still I didn't find my Whatsapp data in gallery. Now after getting some new images and videos through Whatsapp, I checked again. Now I can see those videos and images. But still the old images and videos are "hiding away" from gallery. Why?

I have checked Whatsapp folder. I can still see old images and videos in `whatsapp/media` folder and the new videos and images are added to the corresponding folders along with other images and folders.

How can I show all of my images and videos in gallery?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the trick here is to somehow get the media scan to run again. I would normally expect a reboot to take care of this, but perhaps a more explicit instruction will work.

[As per this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/51800/1131), I'd suggest executing the following ADB command:

```
am broadcast -a android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED -d file:///mnt/sdcard
```

Also, be sure to check that `.nomedia` doesn't occur in any of the folders (or subfolders) of Whatsapp's media directories.